# xy-pic or tikz : which one should I learn?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, xy-pic

I want to learn how to use tikz more in depth. But I wonder wether I should also learn how to use xy-pic, because it seems, at first glance, that xy-pic can do much of what tikz does when it comes to drawing (commutative) diagrams, and is shorter to write.

I have two questions :

1. Wether I would gain something from learning both, or wether I could learn  "only" tikz and in time achieve the same efficiency as with xy-pic in drawing large commutative diagrams?
2. Wether it is common to know both and, maybe, use xy-pic for commutative diagrams, and tikz for more involved drawings, or wether people who are familiar with tikz feel xy-pic is made redundant?

Or am I underestimating the power of xy-pic?

Comment: In the long run, `tikz` is better to learn. There are several arrows that will look better with `tikz` than in `xy` when doing commutative diagrams. Most notably the hook arrow.

Comment: I think that if you use it right (separating presentation and content with styles) `tikz` can be much more readable and maintainable than `xy-pic` and since it can be used for other complex graphics it could be a good investment if should you need to produce other kind of pictures in the future.

Comment: IMHO if you are sending your file to publish I believe that `xy` is more acceptable. Almost all journals use `xy` for diagrams but since `tikz` is newer and it is almost every month being updated, I believe that they prefer traditional package, like `xy`.

Comment: Both of [tikz-cd](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) and [xymatrix](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xymatrix) are excellent tools for commutative diagrams, one might need both over time depending on application and acceptability. It does not harm to have little hands on experience/knowledge on both. Note: Recent years, there has been lot of [pgf/tikz](http://www.ctan.org/topic/pgf-tikz) dependent packages, which is a hint for `tikz` direction .

Comment: If your primary interest is in drawing commutative diagrams, I suggest you learn both xy-pic and `tikz-cd`. The syntax is so similar that learning both should not be a problem. I find the results from `tikz-cd` to be slightly better, but `xy` is probably more acceptable to journals, so it's a good idea to be able to use both.